# Email sending in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5.3

I an using this code in laravel 5.3 for sending email. But it says undefined variable $email, while i have defined the variable already.
This is my code.

```
       $user->save();
         if (!empty($user->save())) {
            $email = 'ppriyadarshi49@gmail.com';
            $mail = Mail::send('email_page', ['verification_key' => $verification_code], function($message) {
            $message->from('prince.priyadarshi@fluper.com', 'Verify');
            $message->to($email)
            ->subject('Verify your email address');
            });
            return view('for_company');

          }
```

And the error is    Undefined variable: email

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing [`use()`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) in closure function as:

```
   $user->save();
     if (!empty($user->save())) {
        $email = 'ppriyadarshi49@gmail.com';
        $mail = Mail::send('email_page', ['verification_key' => $verification_code], function($message) use($email) {
        $message->from('prince.priyadarshi@fluper.com', 'Verify');
        $message->to($email)
        ->subject('Verify your email address');
        });
        return view('for_company');

      }
```